# Homemade physics engine issue regarding linear projection

Tags: game-physics

I am currently in the process of debugging and improving my mostly complete physics engine. I realize that for the purpose of a game, existing engines are generally the way to go, but the experience and self-gratification of programing a practical engine of any kind makes me ecstatic to say the least. So far, I have managed to build a 2D engine that supports circles and rectangles with rotation and friction. It is comparable to most 2D physics engines under low stress circumstances but quickly falls apart at the seams under high stress. For example, when a collapsing tower of rectangles come crashing down, multiple pieces are now interacting directly with each other with very high forces in between. My engine would attempt separate each collision one by one in object pairs but, sometimes, when the engine pushes a pair of objects away from one another, it ends up pushing one or both into other objects, exacerbating the issue. Just like that, the objects would get shoved around and vibrate as the engine goes through something like this in its head:

1. Oops, object A is digging into object B. Move both B away and into object C.
2. Oops, object B is now digging into object C. Move B away and into object A.
3. Repeat 1.

Often times, this process can occur multiple times in a single iteration so when resolving collision for one pair, the engine would sometimes “undo” its resolution in another pair. I have tried searching on the web for physics engine tutorials and info but all of them barely covers anything more than what I already have up and running. Some mentions solving collision as a string of events, but never elaborated on it. Is there any way that I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue might lie in how you apply your collision resolution.  I suspect you are doing something along the lines of:

```
ResolveCollision(ObjA, ObjB)
{
    //calculate necessary velocity/force for separation.

    ObjA.SetVelocity(newVel);
    ObjB.SetVelocity(-newVel);
}
```

Issue here is that, in your example, Stage 2 will override the new velocity from phase 1.  Not good.  What you want is to ADD your new velocity onto the existing one.

Ideally, we'd appreciate seeing some code, but this is my initial suspicion.